# Getting a list of all class variables

Tags: flutter, dart

In my [flutter_native_splash](https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash) package I have a [class](https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/blob/18027f5d210aa895388f900cfe3b287b672708b7/lib/cli_commands.dart#L404C3-L404C3) that contains all the parameters that might be passed in a config file.

```dart
class _Parameter {
  static const android = 'android';
  static const android12Section = 'android_12';
  static const androidScreenOrientation = 'android_screen_orientation';
  // ...
}
```

This way I have one source of truth for parameter names, all in one place.  However, I've noticed that users may have typos in their config file, and it would be nice if my package would catch these typos and alert the user.

So, I would like to compare each config key to this list of parameters.  I could put all the parameters into a list `all`, and then check if `_Parmeters.all.contains(someKey)`, but this is messy, because the list would be large, and if I add a parameter, I must remember to add the definition and also add it to my `all` list.  What would be a cleaner way to store these parameter definitions for easy comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dart:mirrors`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.5/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) library. (**NOTE:** This is an approach using reflection)

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class _Parameter {
  static const android = 'android';
  static const android12Section = 'android_12';
  static const androidScreenOrientation = 'android_screen_orientation';
  // ...
}

void main() {
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(_Parameter);
  List<String> parameters = [];

  classMirror.declarations.forEach((symbol, _) {
    parameters.add(MirrorSystem.getName(symbol));
  });

  print(parameters); // [android, android12Section, androidScreenOrientation, _Parameter]
}
```

Notice that the constructor is also there, so don't forget to remove it.

Comment: This looks like it could be a good solution, but when I tried it, it seems that [mirrors are no longer supported](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150).  Am I missing something?

Comment: The link I gave in the post refers to the documentation of Dart 3.1.5, which is the latest version of Dart. It is currently still supported, but you have to use it with caution.